# how to use the hibernate optimistic-lock property?

Tags: hibernate

I am unable to find enough documentation to fully understand it.

Comment: why is there a vote to close it?

Comment: Probably because your question does not describe what documentation you have consulted, and which particular questions remained. Anybody answering risks to not cover the parts you are interested in, while wasting time describing stuff you already know.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [relevant chapter in the hibernate reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic)?